# Visualizer extension crashed and unable to tevert back to stock (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have recently installed an extension [Readable Expressions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers). But after installing it I am getting an error when I click on the magnifier icon (Which normally shows the visualizer) saying
[image]

I disabled the extension from the extension manager. No changed. I tried to uninstall, but uninstall is disabled.

Please help me how to revert it back to the old way.

I tried restarting visual studio, doesnt make any difference.

Comment: https://github.com/agileobjects/ReadableExpressions/issues/81

Answer (score 1):

ReadableExpressions is my extension - the [Github readme](https://github.com/agileobjects/ReadableExpressions#readme) explains the error you were seeing.

You can uninstall the extension from Add/Remove Programs, or work around [the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29976) by adding the following to your ASP.NET Core csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    true
  </EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
</PropertyGroup>
```